# Filter by group where values in series increase in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': ['cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust2', 'cust2', 'cust2', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust3', 'cust3', 'cust3'],
                   'year': [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
                   'amt': [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5]})

        a  year  amt
0   cust1  2017    2
1   cust1  2018    3
2   cust1  2019    4
3   cust1  2020    5
4   cust2  2017    2
5   cust2  2018    2
6   cust2  2019    3
7   cust2  2020    3
8   cust3  2017    3
9   cust3  2018    3
10  cust3  2019    3
11  cust3  2020    5
```

How do I filter all groups in column 'a' where values in column 'amt' increase from year to year or are "flat" (no increase/no decrease) for a maximum of 2 years.

my result should look like this:

```
        a  result
0   cust1  True
1   cust2  True
2   cust3  False
```

Logic:

cust1 = amt increases every year

cust2 = amt increase every year or is flat for max 2 consecutive years within series

cust3 = amt is flat for 3 or more consecutive years (2017, 2018, 2019)

I know how to check for increase from 1 year to next but struggling to have the additional condition of no increase for max 2 consecutive years.

```
df.sort_values('year').groupby('a')['amt'].pct_change() > 0
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: You say "or are flat for 2 yrs max", shouldn't cust3 be filtered out? Or just display the year when it grew amt?

Comment: can `amt` go down? or only up/same?

Comment: Try setting `.pct_change()` or `.diff()` as a column and using `.rolling(2).agg(['mean', 'sum'])`,

Comment: i edited my expected output. output cannot go down, only up or same for max 2 consecutive years. then has to go up again before it can be flat for 2 consecutive years again.

Answer (score 1):

Since your condition is "flat for 3 years" you don't actually need the diff, only to check if year 1 is equal to year 3 in any 3-year rolling window, or what'll be easy to check with `pandas` is that `max() == min()` in any window.

you can use [`.rolling(3)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), like this:

```py
window3 = df.sort_values('year').groupby('a')['amt'].rolling(3)
cust_needs_filter = (window3.max() == window3.min()).groupby('a').any()
result_df = (~cust_needs_filter).to_frame().rename(columns={"amt": "result"}).reset_index()

print(result_df)
```

Output:

```
       a  result
0  cust1    True
1  cust2    True
2  cust3   False
```

Comment: i have edited my expected output. i will look into understanding .rolling

Comment: @idt_tt great! edited my answer with the necessary modification to get the exact result.